# Since SparkSession is the only entry point, why SparkContext is still available?

Tags: apache-spark

Since SparkSession is the only entry point, why SparkContext is still available? Will SparkContext be deprecated in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a question *"will SparkContext be deprecated in the future?"*, then my answer would be that it depends on the `Spark` further development.

If your question is *"why it is not deprecated and available in a `spark-shell`?"*, then my answer would be that not everybody uses `Dataframes` / `Datasets`.
Moreover, under the hood `Datasets` use `RDDs`. Take a look into [this TableScan interface](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5264164a67df498b73facae207eda12ee133be7d/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/sources/interfaces.scala#L247) that is used to build a `Relation` for the `Dataframe` source: you can notice that it returns `RDD`, and operations with `RDD`s may require `SparkContext` usage at this point.

The statement *"Since SparkSession is the only entry point"* is wrong in your post. Along with the `SparkSession` and `SparkContext`, there is also a `StreamingContext` for the `Spark Streaming` usage.

I am not sure how clear my answer was, but I've tried to clarify you the situation with the different `contexts` at this point in `Spark`: all of them have different purposes and nothing is deprecated.